# Subsetting multiple vectors based on a specific condition

Tags: r

In R I am trying to subset a df with multiple vectors which are categorical. Both vectors are factors and I am trying to return a subsetted vector that meets the following conditions. From the column called Tail, I would like to identify only the Tail's which are Class 1 & 2.

For Example only the final subset should only include tail B-123 and B-888 since they are the only two Tails which have both Class 1 & 2 while the remaining Tails are only of Class 1 or of Class 2. I've been using dplyr filter and specifying conditions but have not been able to yield the correct results.

```
Tail   
B-123
B-645
B-938
B-123
B-645
B-938
B-888
B-888
----------
Class
 1
 2
 1
 2
 2
 1
 1
 2
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am not sure if `Tail` and `Class` are part of the same dataframe or are two seperate vectors. If they are two seperate vectors, maybe you can merge the two vectors in a dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Tail = as.character(Tail), Class = as.character(Class))
```

and then with `dplyr` you can try,

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(Tail) %>%
   summarise(uniq=n_distinct(Class)) %>%
   filter(uniq ==2)

#   Tail   uniq
#  (fctr)  (int)
#1  B-123     2
#2  B-888     2
```

Comment: Yes they are part of the same df. However, I am trying to filter for unique Tails that have Class 1 and also Class 2, not just Class 2's.  Hope this makes sense.  Thanks for trying.

Comment: @Nick Did you try the solution provided? It should work.